# React with TypeScript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'render')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have a super boilerplate React TypeScript file, without any typescript features.

*index.tsx*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

const App = () => (
    <div>
        <h1>yo</h1>
    </div>
);

ReactDom.render(
    <App />,
    document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

And this is the *tsconfig.json*

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNext",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "jsx": "react"
    }
}
```

I don't get any errors in the compilers, but nothing shows up, and in the console I get this error: *TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'render')*

The weird thing is it works perfectly fine if I get rid of typescript and change the same file and entry point to index.jsx instead of index.tsx.

What's happening?

EDIT:

And this is my *package.json*

```
    {
      "name": "o",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack",
        "dev": "webpack serve"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.6",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
        "css-loader": "^6.3.0",
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.26.0",
        "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.3.0",
        "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
        "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
        "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
        "typescript": "^4.4.3",
        "webpack": "^5.53.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.2.1",
        "webpack-obj-loader": "^1.0.4"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "three": "^0.132.2",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please share your `package.json` file

Comment: I added it to the questions

Comment: You don't have any type definition for react, add `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom` to your package.json

Comment: Can you clarify where you get the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'render')`; the IDE or the browser console?

Comment: It happened to me also. It's something to do with Typescript because when I change the file to .jsx it works just fine.
@SamuelGoldenbaum in my case it shows up in the browser's console.
EDIT: I DO have the @types/react and @types/react-dom